# Conditionals in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'd like to create a new variable by combining two variables that look like this:

```
pers_illness<- c("Personal experience with illness", "Personal experience with illness", "None", "None")
fam_illness<- c("Familial experience", "None", "Familial experience", "None")
df<-data.frame(pers_illness, fam_illness)
```

Looks like this:

| pers_illness | fam_illness |
| --- | --- |
| Personal experience with illness | Familial experience |
| Personal experience with illness | None |
| None | Familial experience |
| None | None |

I want to prioritize those that have reported they have a personal experience over those that have familial experience (unless of course they've reported "none"). I think the if-then statement (`if(){}`) might work in this case, but I'm not sure how to use it! I'd like my desired output to look like this:

| pers_illness | fam_illness | exp_illness |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Personal experience with illness | Familial experience | Personal experience with illness |
| Personal experience with illness | None | Personal experience with illness |
| None | Familial experience | Familial experience |
| None | None | None |

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: `df$exp_illness <- ifelse(df$pers_illness == "None", df$fam_illness, df$pers_illness)`. Most operations in R are "vectorized," so it's simpler and more efficient to apply them once to each vector (ie column in a table) instead of using a for loop for each element in those vectors.